# makefile, why spaces in string was merged?

Tags: android, makefile, build

When I read makefile of android build/core/definitions.mk function collapse-pairs, I found I can't understand the logic of space processes below:

```
define collapse-pairs
$(eval _cpSEP := $(strip $(if $(2),$(2),=)))\
$(subst $(space)$(_cpSEP)$(space),$(_cpSEP),$(strip \
    $(subst $(_cpSEP), $(_cpSEP) ,$(1))))
endef
```

> at `$(subst $(_cpSEP), $(_cpSEP) ,$(1))`, "a= b" should be changed to
>   "a =<2 spaces>b", then at `$(subst
>   $(space)$(_cpSEP)$(space),$(_cpSEP),...)`, it should be replace back.
>   but actually, it become "a=b", looks two space in string were merged
>   automatically.

During investigating, I found following strange thing:

```
$ cat test-1.mk
something:="a  =b c=       d e = f"
$(info $(something))
all:
        @echo "something:${something}"

$ make -f test-1.mk
"a  =b c=       d e = f"
something:a =b c= d e = f
```

**How make process those spaces? why were them merged?**

Comment: As almost always seems to be the case, once again someone hiding critical information from themselves.  The very first thing you should always do when you don't understand how a recipe works in make is _remove the `@` from the command line_.  Even better would be to not add them in the first place, at least until your makefile is working properly.  Make will show you _exactly_ what command it will invoke, if you let it, and examining that will often show you where your problem is.

Comment: Thanks! remove "@" can make things clear. but for make script above, how to  explain subst behavior?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the "subst behavior" question.  I will say that generally spaces _after_ commas are removed by make, while spaces after an argument and before the comma is preserved in the argument.  Maybe that would answer your question; if not you'll have to rewrite it to make it clearer (for me, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

first, the fix:

```
something:="a  =b c=       d e = f"
$(info $(something))
all:
    @echo something:${something}
```

It wasn't **make** that merged the spaces, but rather the shell. The command line

```
echo "something:"a  =b c=       d e = f""
```

is interpreted as a list of `something:a` `=b` `c=` `d` `e` `=` `f`. When you remove the quotes around `something:${something}`, **echo** receives one argument with embedded spaces.

If you want **echo** to output the quotes, you must escape them:

```
echo \"something:${something}\"
```

Comment: Thanks, this do explained the behavior of the script, for subst, it that same issue? how I can verify it?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve with `$(subst )`. Probably you have chosen the wrong hammer.